# Ошибка в библиотеке spring data cassandra

Tags: spring, cassandra

В файле **CassandraSimpleTypeHolder**:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.DataType;
...
DataType dataType;
Class javaClass = dataType.asJavaClass();
```

`public abstract class DataType` не содержит метод `asJavaClass()`. Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/DataType.java) на файл класса, хотя в документации он [есть](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/1.0/com/datastax/driver/core/DataType.html).

Версии библиотек **sprint data cassandra 1.4.3** и **cassandra driver core 3.1.0**

Comment: не "в документации он есть", а "есть в документации версии 1.0", т.е. в 3.х его вполне себе легально нету

Comment: А как создать CassandraTemplate класс если метода asJavaClass() нету в классе DataType. (библиотека cassandra driver core-3.1.0)?